# PayPal Rest API PHP cURL login/auth not working anymore

Tags: php, curl, paypal

We set up a PayPal express checkout about 2 weeks ago which worked perfectly until a couple of days ago it didn't.
On PayPal the transactions is ok but when I try to log in with cURL to check the transaction the inital merchant/client login fails but cURL shows no error.
I know that PayPal is upgrading to TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 but I did the test check were our server/site passed.

This is how I initated the communication with paypal (this worked until now):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'CLIENT_ID:SECRET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now if I print out $result its empty, if I print out curl_errno its 0 and curl_error also empty

so because of TLS 1.2 I modified the code like this

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'CLIENT_ID:SECRET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

but it fails exactly the same as the previous code.

What could be the problem? 
or is it possible that if the login is ok the result is empty?

Comment: Have you contacted PayPal themselves about this? You do [exactly what is described in the docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token) so if it suddenly stopped working, the fault is probably on their side. At least they could have more info.

Comment: I posted it to paypal tech support forum but they flagged it as spam. Nice isn't it? But I found the problem. There was actually two. Somehow the app I created previously didn't work anymore, so I had to create a new one. The second problem is that oauth doesn't respond any more to paypal.com you have to use api.paypal.com

Comment: 1. Wut. Okay. 2. Nice! Glad you could fix it.